# Using Minecraft execute command to test for players near coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to test if a player is at specific coordinates using this command in a command block:

```
execute as @a[x=-166,y=4,z=-120,distance=3] run say cool
```

But nothing happens when I trigger it. If I take the `distance=3` part out it works even if I'm not at the coordinates stated.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

So I did [some research](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments), and it turns out that the way `[x=X,y=Y,z=Z]` works without a `distance` selector is different than what it used to be:

> Selects targets based on distance to that exact position. Combine with
> selecting by radius to select only targets at that specific position.

Basically, `distance` is being automatically filled with the distance from the executing position (in this case, the command block) to the coordinates supplied.

When you use the selector form of `distance=3`, you're saying you want players that are exactly 3 metres away from the coordinates specified, and given that coordinates are floating point values, that's basically impossible without teleporting them to a specific position.  Instead, you want to use a range, such as `distance=2..3` (2 to 3 metres away), `distance=..3` (less than/equal to 3 metres away), or `distance=3..` (greater than/equal to 3 metres away).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `positioned` component to specify the executing position and then use `distance` to specify the distance from that position, in your case `[distance=0..1]`.

Unfortunately typing `distance=1` or `[distance=0]` doesn't work, because you have to be EXACTLY at one of these two distances, like millimetres-exact, so you have to use a range of 0 block distance and 1 block distance. And if the execution succeeds when you're still a few steps away from that block, you can change the value of '1' to a number between '0' and '1' like '0.8', which means `[distance=0..0.8]` (note that the two dots are max/min selectors: if you type any number before the two dots, that's the minimum value, and the one after the two dots is the maximum value).

Comment: You should add an example of a full row of command. Btw, as it is, it looks like your answer haven't brought much more than the one already existing.